# How do I find the ppa of a project from its Launchpad page?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

Im usually searching launchpad for interesting projects but sometimes i just cant find the ppa url.
Here is an example: [Marlin on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/marlin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Via the project's maintainer/driver Launchpad profiles

You can look for PPAs *associated* with a Launchpad project by looking at the profiles of the maintainer and/or the driver:

[image]

Click on the links, and look under the *Personal Package Archives* section of their profiles. In this case, you'll find the maintainer has PPAs, but they appear to have nothing to with Marlin; on the other hand, [the driver's profile has the PPA you're looking for](https://launchpad.net/%7Emarlin-devs/+archive/marlin-daily):

[image]

#### 2. Searching *launchpad.net* from Google:

Since all PPAs are on Launchpad, and the PPA page for a program usually contains both its name and the word "ppa", using the `site:` Google search often gives you an easy answer:

- [`site:launchpad.net marlin ppa`](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alaunchpad.net+marlin+ppa)

  [image]
- You can confirm that the link is for a PPA by checking for the `+archive` in the URL shown.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do a search for software in PPAs:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

Another option would be to contact the maintainers of the project and ask them to link the PPA in the project description, that would probably make it easier for people to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Projects do not have PPA's, people (or groups) do. You can tell people and groups from projects because people and groups will have a tilde (~) prepended to their name. You should look at the driver for a particular project, and see if they have a PPA available for the software.

For Marlin, it looks like the driver is marlin-devs, and they appear to have a PPA for it.

https://launchpad.net/~marlin-devs/+archive/marlin-daily